# POSTing KnockoutJS model to MVC controller, List<T> in List<T> is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have little experience with KnockoutJS so please bear with me.

I have a basic example that I want to get working so I can expand it to my project.

For this example you click the button and the AddSku method is called to return QuoteLine data with List.

However, as the diagram shows, BomDetails is empty:

[image: BomDetails Empty]

Models:

```
public class QuoteViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QuoteName { get; set; }
    public IList<QuoteLine> QuoteLines { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    public IList<BomDetail> BomDetails = new List<BomDetail>();
}

public class BomDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateQuote()
{
    QuoteViewModel quote = new QuoteViewModel();
    quote.Id = 10;
    quote.QuoteName = "Test Create Quote";
    quote.QuoteLines = new List<QuoteLine>();

    return View(quote);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateQuote(QuoteViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }

    return RedirectToAction("CreateQuote");
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult AddSku()
{
    QuoteLine line = new QuoteLine();
    line.BomDetails = new List<BomDetail>();

    line.Sku = "TestSku";
    line.Description = "TestDescription";

    line.BomDetails.Add(new BomDetail
    {
       Name = "BOM Detail 1"         
    });

    line.BomDetails.Add(new BomDetail
    {
        Name = "BOM Detail 2",
    });

    return Json(line, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The view:

```
@model EngineeringAssistantMVC.ViewModels.QuoteViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<h2>Create Quote</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateQuote", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "createQuoteForm", @class = "form-horizontal", role = Model, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuoteName)

    <h3>Quote Lines</h3>

    <table class="table master-detail-table" id="receiving-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: QuoteLines">        
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class='form-control' data-bind='value: $data.Sku, attr: { name: "QuoteLines[" + $index() + "].Sku" } ' type='text' readonly='readonly' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class='form-control' data-bind='value: $data.Description, attr: { name: "QuoteLines[" + $index() + "].Description" } ' type='text' readonly='readonly' />
                </td>             
            </tr>
            <tr class="detail-row">
                <td colspan="7">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: BomDetails">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class='form-control' data-bind='value: $data.Name, attr: { name: "BomDetails[" + $index() + "].Name" } ' type='text' readonly='readonly' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

    <h3>Add Sku from Db</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="button" value="Add Sku" id="btnAddSku" class="btn btn-satcom-primary btn-wider" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Submit</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-satcom-primary btn-wider" id="btnSubmit" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    quoteViewModel = new QuoteViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(quoteViewModel);

    $('#btnAddSku').off().on('click', function () {
        AddFromDb();
    });
});

function QuoteViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable('@Model.Id');
    self.QuoteName = ko.observable('@Model.QuoteName');

    self.QuoteLines = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.AddQuoteLine = function (sku, description, bomDetails) {
        self.QuoteLines.push(new QuoteLineViewModel(sku, description, bomDetails));
    }
}

function QuoteLineViewModel(sku, description, bomDetails) {
    var self = this;
    self.Sku = sku;
    self.Description = description;

    self.BomDetails = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.each(bomDetails, function (index, item) {
        self.BomDetails.push(new BomDetailViewModel(item.Name));
    });     
}

function BomDetailViewModel(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = name;
}

function AddFromDb() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddSku", "Test")',
        success: function (line) {
            window.quoteViewModel.AddQuoteLine(line.Sku, line.Description, line.BomDetails);               
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried so many things to get it populated but can't figure out where the problem lies, but I hope it is just something silly that I'm doing or not doing.

I have also tried using ko.mapping but I can't get that working either.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working so hopefully it will help somebody else in the future.

I removed the @Using (Html.BeginForm)

I changed the submit button to a normal button and added data-bind to a fucntion

```
        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-satcom-primary btn-wider" id="btnSubmit" data-bind="click:SaveToDatabase" />
```

The SaveToDatabase function:

```
self.SaveToDatabase = function () {
        var dataToSend = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateQuote", "Test")',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

This correctly sends all the data to the controller.